# How to clone a KOBO Clare HD 8gb SD card using macOS?

Tags: macos, sd-card

I have a newly acquired KOBO Clare HD e-reader that contains a 8GB micro SD Card.  I want to back a clone backup onto a 32GB micro card.

I have a MacBook Pro 2013 running MacOS Catalina v10.15.7

How can I clone the 8GB SD card onto the 32GB SD card using this MacBook Pro?

Comment: What research have you done? What have you tried so far? Why wasn't it satisfactory?

Comment: I would use [this answer from the linked question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/46272/5472) - Disk Utility is less prone to error,  it any of the answers should work.

Comment: I tried using DD Command in terminal and got a password prompt!

% sudo dd bs=1m if=/dev/disk3 of=/dev/disk2 conv=noerror,sync
Password:
dd: /dev/disk2: Permission denied
 %

Is this indicating the /dev/disk2 is password protected?
I used my MacBook Pro Admin password and it was rejected.

Earlier today trying on a WIN1o machine, the linux partition caused somewhat similar errors blocking access to be read using WIN32diskimager.

I've been working this about 18 hours without a successful read/write.